# cannot register a user mongoose nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

So I'm looking to implement passport, however, I'm getting a 500 error

```
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

mongoose and the mongodb server is running, I have taken a look at the terminal and nothing of note error wise is showing.

Here is some code:

register.pug

```
extends ./shared/layout

block content
  section(class='flex items-center flex-wrap' id='hero')
    section(class='w-full py-6 px-6 text-center')
      h1(class='text-4xl uppercase md:text-4xl text-grey-darkest mb-4') Register

  form(class='w-full max-w-md m-auto p-8' action='/register' method='POST')
    section(class='flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-3')
      section(class='w-full md:w-1/2 px-3')
        label(class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2' for='first_name') First Name
        input(class='appearance-none resize-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3' type='text' name='first_name' placeholder='Jane')
      section(class='w-full md:w-1/2 px-3')
        label(class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2' for='last_name') Last Name
        input(class='appearance-none resize-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3' type='text' name='last_name' placeholder='Doe')
    section(class='flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-3')
      section(class='w-full px-3')
        label(class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2' for='email') Email Address
        input(class='appearance-none resize-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3' type='text' name='email' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com')
    section(class='flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-3')
      section(class='w-full px-3')
        label(class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-grey-darker text-xs font-bold mb-2' for='message') Password
        input(class='appearance-none resize-none block w-full bg-grey-lighter text-grey-darker border border-grey-lighter rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3' type='password' name='password' placeholder='password')
        button(href='#' class='inline-block px-4 py-3 border bg-teal-light rounded text-white border-none w-full hover:border-teal hover:bg-teal hover:text-white no-underline mr-2 lg:mt-0' type='submit') Register
```

user.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var app = express();

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: String,
  admin: { type: Boolean, default: false },

  // reset password
  resetPasswordToken: String,
  resetPasswordExpires: Date
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
  var query = {email: email};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var samplePages_controller = require('../controllers/samplePages_controller');
var contacts_controller = require('../controllers/contacts_controller');
var dashboards_controller = require('../controllers/dashboards_controller');
var users_controller = require('../controllers/users_controller');

var User = require('../models/user');

/* samplePages ROUTES */
router.get('/', samplePages_controller.index);
router.get('/about', samplePages_controller.about);

/* users ROUTES */
router.get('/login', users_controller.login);
router.get('/register', users_controller.register);
router.post('/register', users_controller.post_register);

/* dashboards ROUTES */
router.get('/dashboard', dashboards_controller.index);

/* contact ROUTES. */
router.get('/contact', contacts_controller.show);
router.post('/contact/send', contacts_controller.send_contact);

module.exports = router;
```

users_controller.js

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

exports.register = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', { title: 'Rafflefly | Register' });
}

exports.post_register = function(req, res, next) {
  var first_name = req.body.first_name;
  var last_name = req.body.last_name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;

  // validations
  req.checkBody('first name', 'The first name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('last name', 'The last name is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'An account email is required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'This account email is not valid').isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'An account password is required').notEmpty();

  if (error) {
    req.flash('error', 'The form could not send successfully');
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });

    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
      // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
            pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD,
          }
        });
      } else {
        transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
          port: 587,
          auth: {
            user: '********************',
            pass: '********************',
          }
        });
      }
      // setup email data with unicode symbols
      let mailOptions = {
        from: process.env.GLOBAL_EMAIL || 'ben@benbagley.co.uk', // sender address
        to: `${email}`, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Welcome to Rafflefly', // Subject line
        html: `Welcome to Rafflefly` // html body
      };
      // send mail with defined transport object
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
        }

        req.flash('success', 'You are now registered, you can now login!');
        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(user);
    });
  }
};

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
    },
    function(email, password, done) {
      User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!user){
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown Email Address'});
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
          if(err) throw err;
          if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
          }
        });
      });
    }));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });

exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', { title: 'Rafflefly | Login' });
}

exports.post_login = function(req, res, next) {
  res.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
    failureFlash: true })
  );
}
```

I'm at a loss here, I have gone over the documentation and can't see anything I've missed (although I properly have).

Any help here is appricated.

Comment: You should really provide some kind of detailed error. You state " I have taken a look at the terminal and nothing of note error wise is showing" but a 500 error is not descriptive enough to diagnose why you're having issues. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html#the-default-error-handler

Comment: Try to `console.error` all the `error` instances you have in your `register` method. Console.log debugging did never let me down :)

Comment: I tried this @sarneeh but still I'm getting no errors at all https://gyazo.com/dfc98d55c9f8815e75a6bea651b34f66

Comment: Could you please at least explain when are you getting that 500 error?

Comment: I'm getting the error when submitting the registration form @LuisPinto

Answer (score 0):

First, try to edit User model as following:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: String,
    admin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
});

UserSchema.methods.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback) {
    var userObj = this;
    userObj.findOne({email: email}, callback);
}

UserSchema.methods.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
    var userObj = this;
    userObj.findById(id, callback);
}

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Second part is passport setup

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var async = require('async');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/User');
var secrets = require('../config/secrets');

/**
 * GET /login
 * Login page.
 */
exports.getLogin = function (req, res) {
    if (req.user) return res.redirect('/authenticated/view/...');
    res.render('login', {
        title: 'Login'
    });
};

/**
 * POST /login
 * Sign in using email and password.
 */
exports.postLogin = function (req, res, next) {
    req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.assert('password', 'Password cannot be blank').notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        req.flash('errors', errors); //!TODO
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }

    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!user) {
            req.flash('errors', { msg: info.message });
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.redirect('/authenticated/view/...');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
};


exports.index = function (req, res, next) {
    return res.redirect('/');
}
/**
 * GET /logout
 * Log out.
 */
exports.logout = function (req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
};

/**
 * GET /signup
 * Signup page.
 */
exports.getSignup = function (req, res) {
    if (req.user) return res.redirect('/authenticated/view/...');
    res.render('signup', {
        title: 'Create account'
    });
};

/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account.
 */
exports.postSignup = function (req, res, next) {
    var user = new User({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, existingUser) {
        if (existingUser) {
            req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address already exists.' });
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        req.assert('confirmPassword', 'Passwords are diffrent!').equals(req.body.password);

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.redirect('/authenticated/view/...');
            });
        });
    });
};

/**
 * GET /account
 * Profile page.
 */
exports.getAccount = function (req, res) {
    res.render('account/profile', {
        title: 'Manage your profile'
    });
};

/**
 * POST /account/profile
 * Update profile information.
 */
exports.postUpdateProfile = function (req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        user.email = req.body.email || '';
        user.profile.name = req.body.name || '';
        user.profile.gender = req.body.gender || '';
        user.profile.location = req.body.location || '';
        user.profile.website = req.body.website || '';

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash('success', { msg: 'Changes saved' });
            res.redirect('/account');
        });
    });
};

/**
 * POST /account/password
 * Update current password.
 */
exports.postUpdatePassword = function (req, res, next) {
    req.assert('password', 'Password has to be at least 4 length').len(4);
    req.assert('confirmPassword', 'Passwords are diffrent!').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        req.flash('errors', errors);
        return res.redirect('/account');
    }

    User.findById(req.user.id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        user.password = req.body.password;

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.flash('success', { msg: 'Password changed propertly' });
            res.redirect('/account');
        });
    });
};

/**
 * POST /account/delete
 * Delete user account.
 */
exports.postDeleteAccount = function (req, res, next) {
    User.remove({ _id: req.user.id }, function (err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        req.logout();
        req.flash('info', { msg: 'Account deleted' });
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};
```